# Subsetting dataframe by a subdataframe vs a series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm learning data science in datacamp and a doubt came to my mind: if we have a dataframe `cars` structured like

```
     cars_per_cap        country  drives_right
US            809  United States          True
AUS           731      Australia         False
JPN           588          Japan         False
IN             18          India         False
RU            200         Russia          True
MOR            70        Morocco          True
EG             45          Egypt          True
```

then I can filter only the cars that have `drives_right = True` by typing `print(cars[cars['drives_right']])`. This will return the following:

```
     cars_per_cap        country  drives_right
US            809  United States          True
RU            200         Russia          True
MOR            70        Morocco          True
EG             45          Egypt          True
```

and that is because `cars['drives_right']` is a series. I got to wonder what would happen if I used the data frame `cars[['drives_right']]` instead and I got the following:

```
     cars_per_cap country drives_right
US            NaN     NaN         True
AUS           NaN     NaN          NaN
JPN           NaN     NaN          NaN
IN            NaN     NaN          NaN
RU            NaN     NaN         True
MOR           NaN     NaN         True
EG            NaN     NaN         True
```

does any of you know why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

let me explain through this

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'cars_per_cap': 89, 'country': 'United States', 'drives_right': True },{'cars_per_cap': 289, 'country': 'Australia', 'drives_right': False },{'cars_per_cap': 189, 'country': 'Japan', 'drives_right': False } ]
cars =pd.DataFrame(data, index=["US", "AUS", "JPN"])
print (cars)
```

output :

```
     cars_per_cap        country  drives_right
US             89  United States          True
AUS           289      Australia         False
JPN           189          Japan         False
```

You can see the index created here are 'US', 'AUS', 'JPN'

```
#With three  column indices, last values same as dictionary key , others not 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['US', 'AUS', 'JPN'], columns=['a', 'b', 'drives_right'])
print (df1)
```

output :

```
      a   b  drives_right
US  NaN NaN          True
AUS NaN NaN         False
JPN NaN NaN         False
```

Please see , df1 DataFrame is created with some column index other than the dictionary key; thus, appended the NaN’s in place for the values.

Same reason , when you use :

```
print(cars[cars['drives_right']])

  cars_per_cap        country  drives_right
US            89  United States          True
```

when you use :

```
print (cars[cars[['drives_right']]])

     cars_per_cap country drives_right
US            NaN     NaN         True
AUS           NaN     NaN          NaN
JPN           NaN     NaN          NaN
```

Comment: I don't understand why one thing implicates the other